# Как добавить в таблицу jscrollpane

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Кто знает в чем проблема? Хочу сочетать таблицу и `jscrollpane`, когда начинаю использовать этот плагин все ломает, не получается зафиксировать `thead`. Кто то сталкивался с таким? Если удалить класс `scroll-pane` то все работает правильно, только без стилизации скролла.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  window.onload = function(){
    var tableCont = document.querySelector('#table-cont')
    /**
     * scroll handle
     * @param {event} e -- scroll event
     */
    function scrollHandle (e){
      var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
      this.querySelector('thead').style.transform = 'translateY(' + scrollTop + 'px)';
    }

    tableCont.addEventListener('scroll',scrollHandle)
  };
  
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({
        showArrows: false,
        contentWidth: '0px',
        autoReinitialise: true
    }).bind(
        'mousewheel',
        function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    );

  
});
```

```css
.table-cont{
  /**make table can scroll**/
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  /** add some style**/
  /*padding: 2px;*/
  background: #ddd;
  margin: 20px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px #ddd;
}
thead{
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jScrollPane/2.2.0/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jScrollPane/2.2.0/script/jquery.jscrollpane.js"></script>

<h1 >132 qwe 123qwe </h1>
  <div class='table-cont scroll-pane' id='table-cont'>
   <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">4</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">5</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">6</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">7</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">8</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">9</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">10</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">11</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">12</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">13</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```